# questions that can be asked for linear regression and logistic regression

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, data-mining, predictive-models

I am preparing a potential interview, which can involve detailed questions on linear regression and logistic regression. Besides going over the textbook, could you share some possible interview questions on these topics based on your industrial and education experiences? Thanks.

Comment: Describe polynomial order and how higher orders may be required for a specific application?

Comment: There are so many possibilities...could you be more specific as to what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: More use to ask candidates technical questions that naturally arise from discussion of their past experience & the job you'll be wanting them to do than to set them a quiz. You risk making the interview boring & putting them off working for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) with case-control data (selection on $Y$), how can you use logistic regression? Is it valid? How is parameter estimates (and their interpretations) affected?
2) tell us about over-dispersion in binomial data. Why is it a problem? What is it? What can you do with it? How is logistic regression affected?  Is there some alternatives to logistic regression in that case? 
3) tell us about modeling of interactions in linear and logistic regression. How does it differ? How does interpretations differ in those two cases?

Answer (score 3):

What are some of the [assumptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression#Assumptions) of linear regression?

What type of regression should you use with an outcome that is yes/no? (Yes, this is simple, but yes, it is asked quite frequently!)